# Django OneToOne fields conflicting when creating both instances in same view

Tags: django

I'm sure I'm missing something here.

I do have two models, Foo and Bar like so

```
class Foo(models.Model):
   bar = models.OneToOneField(Bar)
   ..


class Bar(models.Model):
   foo = models.OneToOneField(Foo)
   ..
```

Now I have to create new instances for both of them which will be mapped 1-1. Creating an instance, it requires me to map name to the other instance which doesn't exist yet.

How to handle with this? Is there a way to create an empty instance beforehand or s.th.?

```
foo_instance = Foo(bar=bar_instance)
foo_instance.save()


# won't work since bar_instance not yet created
..
```

Comment: Why are you defining both models with OneToOne relations between them?

Comment: ah I thought this is mandatory. Each Foo instance will be related to one Bar instance and vice versa. So would ForeignKey be better?

Comment: The OneToOne field is perfect if you need to enforce only one relation between this two models, but you don't need to use in both models. If you use something like class Foo(models.Model): bar = models.OneToOneField(Bar, related_name="foo") you'll be connecting both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare relationship only one time.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
   ..


class Bar(models.Model):
   foo = models.OneToOneField(Foo)
   ..
```

Then, you call your objects in both sides of the instances.

```
foo_instance = Foo()

bar_instance = Bar(foo=foo.instance)

bar_instance.foo
foo_instance.bar # As the name of the class, but in lowercase
```

[Here the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)